# How does Node communicate with the operating system if it's V8 is a sandboxed environment?

Tags: node.js

Without spending nights of digging through the source code, I was hoping someone could shed some light on how Node is able to communicate with the operating system and do such things as writing files to the file system? I've even seen a package which allows bidirectional communication with the .NET runtime.

My very simple understanding of Node is that it's the V8 engine taken from Chome and packaged up. However writing files to the file system using JavaScript from within Chrome is not possible.

How does Node allow JavaScript to extend past its sandbox? What special syntax is used by JavaScript to call out to external C++ libs?

Comment: These limitations you mention are not inherent to Javascript as much as how Javascript is sandboxed by browsers.  It's just a programming language.  The V8 engine is also extensible, so anything the Node implementation doesn't have in terms of direct access can be done via 3rd party libraries written in C++.

Comment: Understand that, what I had trouble understanding was how JavaScript communicated with these libraries written in c++. I thought there was a special JavaScript keyword. The link provided by @slebetman explains this though. The magic happens in the require() function which wires it up.

Answer (score 2):

V8 in Chrome isn't sandboxed because V8 is sandboxed.  It's sandboxed because Chrome sandboxes it.

Comment: my god. crispy. :)

Answer (score 1):

Only way to use the operating system functionality is to make system call. For example to create a new file Windows exports systemcall CreateFile(). The V8 engine interprets the javascript code and makes call to NODEJS core library

NodeJs itslef is written in c/C++ . calls are made through V8 engine to NODEJS core libraries and its these library which perform the tasks.

Comment: And how do these core libraries written in JavaScript call out to them? I wasn't aware that JavaScript has special syntax to call out to Windows/Linux APIs'.

Comment: A lot of the core libraries are written in C/C++ not javascript - that's how node does it. You have two choices when you want to write a library in node - write it in javascript or write it in C.

Comment: See this for how to write libraries for node in C++ : http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: Thanks @slebetman that link explains it very well. It seems that the magic happens in the "require()" function. It's a shame I can't mark it as an answer.